# Error while compiling a Flutter application for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, flutter, flutter-windows

Hello I hope you are well.
I have a problem when compiling my Flutter application for the Windows platform.
Indeed when I launch my Flutter application by pressing the "Run" button of VScode (or of any IDE compatible with Flutter) I have this error below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(234,5): error MSB6006: Arrêt de "cmd.exe" avec le code 1. [C:\Users\Acer Aspire\VSCodeProjects\atlas_workspace\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

But strangely by using the Powershell terminal, by being at the root of my project, by executing the command `flutter run -d Windows` the application compiles and launches without problem.

Can you tell me what the problem is? And how to solve it? Thanks

My version of Windows : windows 10 version 20H2 ( operating system verion 19042.884)

The output of the flutter doctor command:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19042.844], locale fr-FR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

The output of the flutter --version command:

```
Flutter 2.0.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4d7946a68d (2 weeks ago) • 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
Engine • revision 3459eb2436
Tools • Dart 2.12.2
```

P.S: I have Visual Studio 2019 and C++ tools installed on my OS

Comment: Please provide complete error!

Comment: The error you show is just the final line stating that `cmd.exe` returned `1` and not zero as exxpected for successful builds. That error message isn't useful for any diagnosis, since it's the same for **any** failed build. You should provide the error messages, which are listed before that line.

Comment: That's all the console shows me @pritamparab

Comment: @Delucis What are you actually typing in? There should be some verbose mode, bor a separate error log in case. As mentioned, that specific console output is completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug, it's because you have spaces in your user name **Acer Aspire** :

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73644

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75611

Comment: I checked the solutions proposed in the links you sent me. That said, the solution is that I can rename my folder ?

Comment: And why when i run `flutter run -d windows` directly in the terminal it works ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!I had to change my user name so that it could not contain any space and the problem is solved

so `C:\Users\Acer Aspire\VSCodeProjects\atlas_workspace\` is now `C:\Users\AcerAspire\VSCodeProjects\atlas_workspace\`

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

1. flutter clean 2) flutter pub get
   run in commmand panel. it solved my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).